# Edge Scrolling resets and disables itself

Tags: settings, scrolling, reset

Every time I open the settings window or naviate in the settings window the edge scrolling resets and I have to go in and click it again.

I'm trying to make sure that edge scrolling stays on.

xinput tells me this:

```
$ xinput list-props 11
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (290): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (291): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (292):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (293):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (294):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (295):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (296):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (297):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (298):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (299):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (300):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (301):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (302):    0, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (303):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (304):   0, 1, 0
    libinput Accel Speed (305): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (306): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (307): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (308): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (275): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (276):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (277):    0, 0
    Device Node (278):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (279):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (309):   
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (310):   1
```

It seems to be the only setting that resets. How do I make it permanent? Is it a bug?

EDIT:

Laptop model: HP Compaq 6735b

OS version: Ubuntu 20.04

Bios version: 68GTT Ver. F.0A

It looks like the bios version is from 12/16/2008. Wouldn't be surprising if it's causing problems.

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the make/model of your computer, and we'll check for a newer BIOS.

Comment: Yes, your BIOS is old. Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them... like I missed your last update to your question :-)

Comment: @heynnema It looks like they want me to choose an OS to download it for and there's only windows. What should I do?

Comment: There are 3 possible download files. The last one allows you to create a bootable freeDOS updater on a USB flash, but it still requires Windows to build it. Either temporarily install Windows, or go to a friends house and use their Windows computer to build it. Also, at the web page, flip down the blue triangles to see the docs for each of the upgrade files.

Comment: @heynnema I've ran into more problems and I'm in way over my head. I have no idea what I'm doing. It would be great if I could pm you but it seems I can't. 
I'm sorry. I don't think I can do this yet.

Comment: Tell me where you're hung up and I'll try to help. Did you view the docs at the web site?

Answer (score 0):

You have BIOS 68GTT F.0A.

There's a newer BIOS F.20 available to download [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-compaq-6735b-notebook-pc/3687779).

Note: Do proper backups before updating the BIOS.